# How to cancel IAsyncEnumerable when exception occurs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am using `IAsyncEnumerable` to fetch a lot of data - like this:

```
static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetSequence([EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        var data = await DoSomethingAsync()    // get data from web request
        yield return data;
    }
}
```

Now here is my question: if `DoSomethingAsync` throws an exception (maybe a network issue), I would like to cancel the remaining requests, is it possible?

I am trying below code to handle but still need help:

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = source.Token;

try
{
    IAsyncEnumerable<int> dataCol = GetSequence(token);

    await foreach (var d in dataCol)
    {
        // do ...
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
   source.Cancel(true);
   throw;
}
```

Appreciate if someone has best practices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the original [language proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/async-streams)

```cs
await foreach (var d in dataCol)
{
    // do ...
}
```

is equivalent to;

```cs
{
    E e = dataCol.GetAsyncEnumerator();
    try {
        while (await e.MoveNextAsync()) {
            var d = e.Current;
            // do ...
        }
    }
    finally {
        ... // Dispose e
    }
}
```

Calling `MoveNextAsync` causes your `GetSequence` method to execute up to the next `yield return`, or until an unhandled exception is thrown. Execution of that method will not resume until the next call to `MoveNextAsync`. `GetSequence` and `await foreach` do not run in parallel, they take turns executing more code within the same async task.

> if DoSomethingAsync throws an exception

then `await e.MoveNextAsync()` will re-throw the exception. Then enumerator will be disposed. Then the exception would flow up the stack to the next exception handler.

You don't need to mess around with cancelation tokens to prevent `GetSequence` from resuming execution. In fact breaking out of the `await foreach` loop would also abort execution, as if the `yield return` never resumed. Causing any `finally{}` blocks in your `GetSequence` method to execute, if you had any.

Comment: oh seems i am very stupid.   no need to cancel , it will no longer loop after exception